# GitHub Actions Cannot Find JAR file in Target Directory

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub Actions to build a Docker image and publish it to Docker Hub.

I'm getting an error during the `Build and push` step when it is attempting to build the Docker image because it cannot find the `target` directory.

The Docker build step is looking in `/tmp/buildkit-mount147850474/target` but my JAR is in `/home/runner/work/myrepo/myrepo/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

How do I tell the Docker build step to use the correct directory?

I looked at `working-directory` but the documentation says it is only for `run` steps.

**Error**

```
#6 [3/3] COPY target/*.jar app.jar
#6 ERROR: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount147850474/target: no such file or directory
```

**Log snippet when it saves the JAR**

```
[INFO] Building jar: /home/runner/work/myrepo/myrepo/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**publish.yml**

```
name: Publish Docker Image

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          cache: maven
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      - name: Set output
        id: vars
        run: echo ::set-output name=tag::${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        working-directory:  ${{ github.workspace }}
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ github.repository }}:${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }}
```

Comment: Did you try using this **working-directory** in your **Build and Push** step? `working-directory:  ${{ github.workspace }}/target`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar pipeline but when I use **docker/build-push-action**:

- I have no **working-directory** param
- I have a **context** param set to current directory in **with** map

Could you try to modify your **Build and push** step like this ?

```
- name: Build and push
  id: docker_build
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .    
    push: true
    tags: ${{ github.repository }}:${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }}
```

You can have a look at this example (https://morioh.com/p/2d04d286363b) and also at documentation of this action (https://github.com/docker/build-push-action)